# IIPImage Dynamic Watermarking

Tags: ubuntu, dynamic, apache2, watermark

To kick this off could anyone make a tag for IIPImage? http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/

I'm trying to set up dynamic Watermarking on my server: IIPImage uses Pyramid Tiff Imaging which splits images into tiles. Dynamic watermarking adds watermarks on tiles randomly, to do so you have to specify 3 variables in Server.conf file which is held in Apache2 Mods-Enabled directory. WATERMARK with the location of your watermark, WATERMARK_PROBABILITY how many tiles will have watermarks i.e 0.3 = 30% of them and lastly WATERMARK_OPACITY how opaque it is. http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/images/#watermarking Here's my config:

```
ScriptAlias /fcgi-bin/ "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/"
# Set the options on that directory
<Directory "/fcgi-bin/">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

# Set the handler
AddHandler fastcgi-script fcg fcgi fpl

# Initialise the FCGI server - set some default values
FastCgiServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi \
-initial-env LOGFILE=/var/log/iipsrv.log \
-initial-env VERBOSITY=3 \
-initial-env JPEG_QUALITY=90 \
-initial-env MAX_IMAGE_CACHE_SIZE=10 \
-initial-env MAX_CVT=5000 \
-initial-env WATERMARK=/IIPServer/images/watermark.tif \
-initial-env WATERMARK_PROBABILITY=0.3 \
-initial-env WATERMARK_OPACITY=0.5 \
-initial-env MEMCACHED_SERVERS=localhost
```

And here's my log file after start up:

```
<----------------------------------->
Fri Oct 19 9:53:02 2012

IIPImage Server. Version 0.9.9
*** Ruven Pillay <ruven@users.sourceforge.net> ***

Verbosity level set to 3
Running in FCGI mode

Setting maximum image cache size to 10MB
Setting filesystem prefix to ''
Setting default JPEG quality to 90
Setting maximum CVT size to 5000
Setting 3D file sequence name pattern to '_pyr_'
Loaded watermark image '/IIPServer/images/watermark.tif': setting probability to 0.3 and   opacity to 0.5
Memcached support enabled. Connected to servers: 'localhost' with timeout 86400


Initialisation Complete.
<----------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was that all the images loaded prior to setting dynamic watermarking were cached in memcache as well as browser cache, clearing those fixed the problem.